# Network Graph Theory Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, network

I have a small question regarding the following problem:

> Suppose that newborn nodes come in groups of n in each period. Suppose
> that
> they attach a fraction f of their links uniformly at random to other newborn
> nodes, and a fraction 1 − f to older nodes via preferential attachment. Using a
> continuous time mean-field approximation, develop an expression for the degree
> distribution. m represents the number of links made by each newborn node.

However, one of the things I am unsure about is why the number of links each newborn forms with another newborn node is $$m(1+f)$$

Why not $$mf$$

I understand that the number of links to each older node is $$m(1-f)n$$

Unsure on this small detail.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is $m$????

Comment: number of links that  any newborn node forms to existing nodes

Comment: any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: If $m$ is the total number of the links for each node, then however you distribute the links the equation $mf + m(1-f) = m$ should hold. You are giving two different definitions on $m$. Is it the total number of links per each newborn or the number of links with the existing nodes?

Comment: According to the solution: we have four things

1) Let $m$ be the number of links that each newborn node adds each period.
2) Each newborn node ends up with $m(1+f)$ links as it enters.
3) Then, $n(1-f)m$ are added via preferential attachment to older nodes.
4) The total degree of all nodes at time t is $2tmn$

Its mainly the $m(1+f)$ i dont really get.